# Authentication fails when running neo4j container in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, neo4j

Hello I am trying to containerize a neo4j service into a docker container on a windows host using docker for windows. However I have an issue when running this docker compose in that when trying to log on to the neo4j browser the authentication is not updated and you have to log in using neo4j/neo4j as opposed to the set neo4j/test.

This is the compose file in question

```
 version: '3.7'
services:
    neo:
        image: neo4j:3.5.23
        environment:
            NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled: 'true' 
            NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled: 'true' 
            NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config: 'true'  
            JAVA_OPTS: '-Xmx1g'
            NEO4J_AUTH: 'neo4j/test'
            NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_advertised__address: 'localhost:7473'
            NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address: 'localhost:7474'
            NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address: 'localhost:7687'
        ports: 
            - 0.0.0.0:7474:7474
            - 7687:7687
        volumes:
            -   type: volume
                source: neo4j_data
                target: /var/lib/neo4j/data
            -   type: bind 
                source: c:/users/xmain/documents/docker/eventstore/neo4j/neo4j3523/import/
                target: /var/lib/neo4j/import
            -   type: volume 
                source: neo4j_logs
                target: /logs
            -   type: bind
                source: c:/users/xmain/documents/docker/eventstore/neo4j/neo4j3523/plugins/
                target: /plugins 
volumes:
    neo4j_data:
    neo4j_logs:
```

However when running the container as a simple command such as this:

```
docker run 
--name testneo4j 
-p7474:7474 -p7687:7687  
-v $PWD/neo4j3523/data:/data 
-v $PWD/neo4j3523/logs:/logs 
-v $PWD/neo4j3523/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import 
-v $PWD/neo4j3523/plugins:/plugins --env NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/test 
--env  NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_advertised__address="localhost:7473" 
--env  NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_advertised__address="localhost:7474" 
--env NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address="localhost:7687"   
-e NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled=true 
-e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true 
-e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config=true  
-e JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx1g' 
neo4j:3.5.23
```

It works! So what am I missing in this compose file?

Comment: Can you try removing the volumes and then reload the containers : ```docker-compose down --volumes` and then `docker-compose up -d` ?